# MYSQL Query Optimization- Joins/Unions vs. table query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

This is somewhat of a conceptual question. In terms of query optimization and speed, I am wondering which route would have the best performance and be the fastest. Suppose I am using JFreeChart (this bit is somewhat irrelevant). The entire idea of using JFreeChart with a MYSQL database is to query for two values, an X and a Y. Suppose the database is full of many different tables, and usually, the X and the Y come from two different tables. Would it be faster, in the query for the chart, to use joins and unions to get the two values...or... first create a table with the joined/union values, and then run queries on this new table (no joins or unions needed)? This would all be in one code mind you. So, overall: joins and unions to get X and Y values, or create a temporary table joining the values and then querying the chart with those.

Comment: It depends on how big the tables are, what else is in them, how are they indexed, how often are they updated, how often are they queried, with what indexes, etc. This question will probably be closed as too broad.

Comment: In general, even DBAs will benchmark both routes and go with the fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would, of course, be faster to pre-join the data and select from a single table than to perform a join. This assumes that you're saving one lookup per row and are properly using indexes in the first place.

However, even though you get performance improvements from dernormalization in such a manner, it's not commonly done. A few of the reason why it's not common include:

- Redundant data takes up more space
- With redundant data, you have to update both copies whenever something changes
- JOINs are fast

JOINs on multiple rows can improve (they don't always require a lookup per row) with such things as the new Batched Key Access joins in MySQL 5.6, but it only helps with some queries, hence you have to tell MySQL which join type you want. It's not automatic.

Comment: Okay thanks. But say the code is written so these temporary tables are formed, used as a source of select statements for the charts, and then the code itself runs statements to delete the temporary tables. Would this be an optimal way to run the code. For specificity, the tables in the database generally consist of thousands of records, multiple columns...so not a small database. If that influences anything. Or would it be better to just run queries when making the charts with join commands and whatnot.

Comment: @user3794422, ultimately it's up to you whether you want to denormalize the data. If it's what you need to do to get acceptable performance, then no one's going to say you're doing the wrong thing. Just avoid pre-optimization. If you don't need it, keep it simple. Take a look at memory tables for your precalculated data if it doesn't update often.